# Gradle "application" plugin changing entrypoint script names

Tags: gradle

I am using the Gradle [Application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin to package an app so it can be run in a Docker container. Locally this all works fine and the only non-default Gradle build statements I use are:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
// Rest of build file declaring dependencies, etc.
mainClassName = 'com.example.MyApp'

distributions {
  main {
    baseName = 'my-app'
  }
}
```

This results in a launch script in `<app_base>/bin/my-app.sh`.

But when I build the app on Jenkins the launch script is `bin/CI_my-app_develop` i.e. it adds `CI_` and the current branch as a suffix.

How can I disable this behaviour?

Comment: The most promising approach I've found so far is creating a custom `CreateStartScripts` type task but I feel like it should be configurable without having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a default `CreateStartScripts` task as follows:

```
createStartScripts {
    applicationName = 'my-app'
}
```

No need to create a custom task for that.